# Closed Operations in Spherical Space

Tags: linear-algebra, spherical-geometry

Euclidean vector arithmetic (addition/subtraction) is not closed under a spherical space. For example:

> $\mathbb{S}^2=\{v \in{\mathbb{R}^3}|\|v\|=1\}$
>   We have $(1, 0, 0)\in\mathbb{S}^2$ and $(0, 1, 0)\in\mathbb{S}^2$.
>   However, $(1, 0, 0)+(0, 1, 0)=(1, 1, 0)\notin\mathbb{S}^2$.

Are there "similar" arithmetic operators that are closed under spherical spaces?

I'm interested in high-dimensional spaces, so an answer for any dimension $n$ would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; one can view the sphere as the complex numbers plus infinity, and then both addition and multiplication are closed operations.

Also, for points that are not opposite of each other, you can take their sum as you did above and then divide that by its length to get a new point on the sphere.

You can also view two points on the sphere as unit vectors. If they are not perpendicular, you can take their cross product and normalize the resulting vector to be a new unit vector.

Edit: You can't define a nice addition on spheres except those of dimension 1 or 3:[Is there an easy way to show which spheres can be Lie groups?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12453/is-there-an-easy-way-to-show-which-spheres-can-be-lie-groups). So associativity or inverses or an identity must not work out for the 2-sphere.

Comment: How can the complex numbers (plus infinity) be viewed as the unit sphere?

Comment: Allow me to refine - how can this be extended to $n$ dimensions?

Comment: Regarding your suggestion for normalizing after addition - this operator is neither associative nor commutative.

Comment: I edited my answers. The complex numbers plus infinity is called the Riemann sphere.