# Lie Group structure on $S^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, normal-subgroups, unitary-matrices, hopf-fibration

I see that people say there is no Lie group structure on $S^2$. But $S^2$ can be identified with $SU(2)/U(1)$ by the Hopf fiberation. Since $U(1)$ is also a normal subgroup in $SU(2)$, can't you associate the quotient group structure to $S^2$?

What is wrong with this association? 
Thanks!

Comment: That copy of $U(1)$ is not normal in $SU(2)$.

Comment: @Max What do you mean by "that copy"? I thought elements of U(1) commute with every element of SU(2), so it ought to be normal?

Comment: There are many subgroups of $SU(2)$ that are isomorphic to $U(1)$, but none of them are normal. There is a copy of $U(1)$ in $U(2)$ which is central- that's probably what you have in mind. My suggestion would be to write out explicitly the Hopf fibration to see what's going on.

Comment: @Max Thanks a lot. This helps a lot.

Answer (score 3):

The group $U(1)$ is *not* a normal subgroup of $SU(2)$. For  instance,\begin{multline}\begin{bmatrix}\frac12+\frac i2&-\frac12+\frac i2\\\frac12+\frac i2&\frac12-\frac i2\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\theta)&-\sin(\theta)\\\sin(\theta)&\cos(\theta)\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}\frac12+\frac i2&-\frac12+\frac i2\\\frac12+\frac i2&\frac12-\frac i2\end{bmatrix}^{-1}=\\=\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)&0\\0&\cos(\theta)-i\sin(\theta)\end{bmatrix}\notin U(1).\end{multline}

And people don't just say that there is no Lie group structure on $S^2$. They [prove it](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1417787/446262).

Comment: Thanks very much. I was initially thinking $U(1)$ as the group of scalar multiplications, but the determinant of those matrices is not even one, so not even in $SU(2)$, so I was certainly wrong. But then if you take $U(1)$ to be the $SO(2)$ subgroup in $SU(2)$, it would not be normal, as you showed. Also thanks for the link for the proof. It is very enlightening.