# Does $ S^n $ admit a group structure?

Tags: group-theory, spheres

I know that some $ S^n $ s have group structures, whereas others do not.

For example,

$ S^0 = \{\pm 1\} \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$,

$ S^1 = \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} $,

$ S^3 = \{a+bi+cj+dk:a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=1\} $, a multiplicative subgroup of the real quaternion algebra.

On the other hand, $ S^{2n} $ with $ n \geq 1 $ cannot have a group structure. Proposition 2.29 of A. Hatcher's Algebraic Topology (on page 135) states that $ \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} $ is the only nontrivial group that can act freely on $ S^{2n} $. But if $ S^{2n} $ itself was a group, then it acts freely on itself.

I want to know whether there is a complete classification theorem about for which $ n $ does $ S^n $ admit a group structure (not necessarily a Lie group structure). Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12453/is-there-an-easy-way-to-show-which-spheres-can-be-lie-groups

Comment: You say you don't require a Lie group structure, but do you still want a *topological* group structure? Because if not, then since all spheres have the same cardinality (apart from the zero dimensional one) they all have at least one group structure.

Comment: @ArnaudD. I think the op requires that the topology be compatible with group operations, i.e. a topological group structure.