# If $S^a$ is a sphere which acts transitively on itself, then $a\in \{0,1,3\}$.

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

I'm reading an article in which the author says that a sphere $S^a$ which acts transitively on itself must be $S^0$, $S^1$ or $S^3$. And I really cannot see why.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, any sphere that is a Lie group at all must be a 0, 1, or 3-sphere. For a proof, see [Is there an easy way to show which spheres can be Lie groups?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12453/is-there-an-easy-way-to-show-which-spheres-can-be-lie-groups)